# Cannot connect to heroku mysql database clearDB using mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, heroku, mysql-workbench, cleardb

Not able to connect to the database with cleardb mysql using heroku as web-server deployment, with mysql workbench the following error is described in the image below.

[image]

Comment: What server version is that? MySQL Workbench uses the latest client library (8.0.13 at this point) and that might not work with older servers.

Comment: Are you using an encrypted connection?

Comment: Oh i will check at work tmr which version im using and no, the password is from the cleardb addon which is provided heroku website

Comment: did you ever get the connection to work? I'm having trouble connecting with workbench (using mysql 8) to clearDB

Comment: @Christy hi christy, I figured out that the problem was that my workplace had a VPN, so I couldn't connect directly to the database due to it, so there's no fix for this, in order to make it work, you most likely need to connect to the database of your work